# how to get an svg from one div element to another div element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, append

I have been trying to append SVG as appending other HTML elements but except for the SVG element, all the other HTML elements append.

The following is the one I have tried

my original set of SVGs are dynamically created for a div for example

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div3">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
    <svg height="140" width="500">
        <ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="400" height="110">
        <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </svg>
    <svg height="100" width="500">
        <ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" />
        <ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div id='slides'></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var svgsiblings = $('#div3').children().siblings("svg");
var slides = document.getElementById( 'items2' );
var theDiv ="";
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (currentcheck , currenttype,i) {
        var itemid = "check" + i;
        theDiv  += "<div class='item"
        theDiv  += " ' id='"
        theDiv  += currentcheck+'-'+itemid
        theDiv  += "'> "
        theDiv  += svgsiblings[i-1].outerHTML 
        theDiv  += " </div>";
    }       
}                                 
$('#items2').append(theDiv);
```

by the above JavaScript, I tried to append. but it only appends the HTML I have mentioned below with an empty space at the place where SVG required

the div tag with id #div3 may contain 10 different SVGs. so that I have looped it through a for loop up to 10,

**The Output:**

```
<div id='slides'>
     <div class='item' id='check1'>   </div>
     <div class='item' id='check2'>   </div>
     <div class='item' id='check3'>   </div>
     <div class='item' id='check4'>   </div>
     <div class='item' id='check5'>   </div>         
</div>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 <div id='slides'>
    ​<div class='item' id='check1'> <svg><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /></svg> </div>
    ​<div class='item' id='check2'> <svg><rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg> </div>
    ​<div class='item' id='check3'> <svg><ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" /></svg> </div>
    ​<div class='item' id='check4'> <svg><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/></svg> </div>
    ​<div class='item' id='check5'> <svg><ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" /><ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" /></svg> </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing jQuery with vanilla JS and while that's not a bad thing, it can be confusing. It's good for readability (and best-practices) to use one or the other.

```
$('#div3 svg').each(
   function(i) {
      $('#slides').append(
        $('<div>').append($(this))
                  .addClass('item')
                  .attr('id', `check${i+1}`))
   })
```

This loops through the svg elements in `#div3`, uses `$.append()` as a wrapper for the part that creates a div element and inserts `$(this)` (the svg) inside the new div. Outside of that wrapper, it applies the className and an id.

This *moves* the svg from it's original place into slides. If you wanted to *copy* it over to slides, you would make this small change:

```
...
$('<div>').append($(this).clone())
...
```

```js
// and here's that in one line
$('#div3 svg').each(function(i) { $('#slides').append($('<div>').append($(this)).addClass('item').attr('id', `check${i+1}`))})
```

```css
.item {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div3">
  <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
  <svg height="140" width="500">
        <ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
  <svg width="400" height="110">
        <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </svg>
  <svg height="100" width="500">
        <ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" />
        <ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div id='slides'></div>
```

Comment: I have 10 ddifferent SVGs, thats why i have used a for loop for 10. will this help me for get each 10 SVGs inside each 'item' class

Comment: Yes, can you pls update your question to be clear about what you need and I’ll update the answer.  Maybe give an example of the svgs. I don’t really understand from your comment

Comment: thank you, it works on normal div elements, but it does not work in a bootstrap popover, is there any reason for it

Comment: So, there are the SVGs on your page and when the popover (is this a modal?) appears you want to copy those to the popover right? Is this bootstrap 4 or 5 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233979/discussion-between-mohamed-ashique-ar-rasool-and-kinglish).

Comment: i have created and updated another question about it can you please check it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053069/svg-not-working-inside-a-bootstrap-5-popover