# svg not working inside a bootstrap 5 popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, popover, bootstrap-5

SVG is not working in the popover. Please help me with how to do this.

my SVG should be worked inside a popover and carousel, but SVG is not supporting the popover

I am having a popover, with a carousel for some particular texts, so I needed to have some SVG inside the carousel

I have added a code Snippet so it might be easy for you, And you can see the console where the SVGs has been loaded to that div, but when popover opens it is not appended

Please Help he to do this out

```js
$(function() {
  $('document').ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  });

  $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
      html: true,
      content: function() {
          $('#div3 svg').each(function(i) {  $('#slider2').append($('<div>').append($(this)).addClass('carousel-item').attr('id', `chord${i+1}`))
          });
          $el =  $('.popup').html();
          console.log($el);
          return $el;
      }
  });

  //----- CLOSE
  $('body').on('click', function (e) {
      $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
          if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
              $(this).popover('hide');
          }
      });
  });

  $('.carousel-inner').carousel(); 
});
```

```css
.popup {
    display: none;
}

#div3 {
    display: none;
}

.popover-body {
  padding:0 !important;
}
.popup-inner {
    width: 170px;
    background: #fff;
}
.popup-close {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    line-height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background: #afafaf;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

.popup-close:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #e72222;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
.pop-head, .pop-footer {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    align-items: center;
    background: #44769e;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
.pop-head:hover, .pop-footer:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #44769e;
}
.pop-head i {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.pop-footer {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
.pop-footer i {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.frame {
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 0 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #b1b1b1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="mt-5">
    <a class="tag" tabindex="0" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="click" data-bs-original-title="" title="">C</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <a href="#" class="pop-head"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        <div class="frame">
            <div id='carousel' class='carousel slide' data-bs-ride='carousel'> 
                <div class='carousel-inner' id="slider2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="pop-footer"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> Play</a>
        <a href="#" class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1">x</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="div3">
  <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
  <svg height="140" width="500">
        <ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
  <svg width="400" height="110">
        <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </svg>
  <svg height="100" width="500">
        <ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" />
        <ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

[check the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxshique/cj4x9pt7/1/)

Comment: Can you make this runnable ?

Comment: @RobertLongson - it's actually appending a SVG to a div which is then appended to #slider2

Comment: I have updated, i think now it might be clear for every one

Comment: @Swati I have made it runnable

Comment: Its working on lower version of bootstrap not sure why it doesn't work with version 5 .